# How to add dynamic content type in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have a service to make HTTP requests as below. I am trying to add dynamic content type in the request header in the service.

How I can add the content type as an extra argument in the `apiCall` function?

```js
@Injectable()
export class AjaxService {
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

    apiCall(
        data: any,
        url: string,
        method: 'DELETE' | 'GET' | 'HEAD' | 'POST' | 'JSONP' | 'PUT',
        isRawUrlFormat: boolean = false
    ) {
        if (isRawUrlFormat === false) {
            url = environment.apiUrl + '/' + url;
        }

        let request$: Observable<any>;

        switch (method) {
            case 'GET':
                request$ = this._http.get(url, { observe: 'response' });
                break;
            case 'POST':
                request$ = this._http.post(url, data, { observe: 'response' });
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                request$ = this._http.put(url, data, { observe: 'response' });
                break;
            default:
                request$ = this._http.request(method, url, {
                    observe: 'response'
                });
        }

        return request$.pipe(
            map((apiResult: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                const responseObject = apiResult.body;
                return responseObject;
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are trying to do the http requests dynamically? Normally if you created a service you would just create a custom method for each http request and then import that service and call the get,post,put,delete, etc... method when u need it?

```
Some Class...    
export Class AjaxService{
    
    httpGET(params){
        ...some code
    }
    
    httpPOST(params){
        ...some code
    }
    
    httpPUT(params){
        ...some code
    }
    
    httpDELETE(params){
        ...some code
    }
    
    
}

import AjaxService;

AjaxSerive.httpGET(api_url).subscribe(res => {
    results = res;
})

AjacSerive.httpPOST(api_url, data).pipe(
    map(res: HttpResponse<any> => {
        results = res;
    })
}
```

These methods are async, they will not return your data, they will return Observables or Subscriptions. You will need to deal with them in the Class that you are importing the service to so that you can bind the data to specified variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have already created a similar Service, check my example here: https://github.com/ferhado/ferhado/blob/master/projects/http/src/lib/http.service.ts

And here on NPM
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ferhado/http